# Birt Mapit not working in Birt-Viewer

Tags: birt

I have created few maps using the mapit library of Birt. The maps are working fantastic in Birt Designer. However, when I put the same report in Birtviewer, the map does not load. My question is whether this is a compatibility issue of Mapit with java8 or birtviewer that it does not work in birt viewer?

My second question is how can I actually see whether the birt library file is being read correctly and whether it could be a problem with reading the library file?

Arif

Comment: Inspect BIRT engine logs of your Webviewer, it probably contains the cause of the issue. If this library can't be reached it will be explicitely mentionned in logs.

Comment: OK, I have found something more. The library was at correct location and it was being accessed. However the map loads in preview but does not work in frameset. Is there anything I could do to make it work in frameset?

Comment: You should inspect the console of your web browser to see if there is a javascript error when the report is rendered through frameset mode. For example use Chrome console. If does not show any error, may be you could post a sample report using this library i would have a look

Comment: I have attached a zip file to dropbox that contains a report design, library file and the data folder. It has flat file data so you probably need to change the path to absolute before putting them on birtviewer. If you manage to deploy it on birtviewer using relatve path, please let me know how you did it. Also I want to know if you can manage to run it using frameset. Here is the link to dropbox [link]https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60353029/GreenIndex.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike "preview" mode, the frameset servlet loads the report through an ajax query. Problem is the Eclipse Webviewer does not make use of a framework such jquery to handle ajax: only the first html script tag is triggered.

Your sample works with the portlet viewer i developed because jquery handles all this ajax stuff automatically. To make it work with the frameset servlet of the Eclipse WebViewer, i tried a *quick and dirty* workaround, only tested with Chrome & Firefox:

**1/ I added this fragment at the end of your first script tag:**

```
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("Evaluate ajax html...");
    var scripts = document.getElementsByName("scriptMap");
    for (var i=0;i<scripts.length;i++) {
      if (scripts[i].text!=null) eval(scripts[i].text)
    }   
}, 1000);
```

**2/ I also added a name "scriptMap" allowing to select the 2 remaining script tags** For example here is the last script:

```
<script name="scriptMap">
    setTimeout(actuate.birt.maps.google.start, 1);
</script>
```

This way the sample runs finely with a WebViewer frameset.

Furthermore, if you need to deploy a flat file as relative path you can manage this by using a file URI such described below. It means in your sample you have to declare two distinct datasource, one for each file. I hope it will help.

[image: Relative path for a flat file]

Comment: Many thanks. I will check it. You have been a great help in my previous posts too...load of thanks

Comment: Hi, Many thanks. Can you please attach the sample that you worked on. I have put the above two pieces of code at the end of the first script tag. This did show the map but the icons on map are somehow still not showing up. The google map in frameset is showin up though